# Is there any counterpart of MATLAB function numel in java?

Tags: java, matlab

I'm trying to use [numel](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/numel.html) (function available in Matlab) in java.
Are they any implementations of this function available in java?

Comment: Just as a sidenote, if you have a M by N by Z matrix or array, numel will print out MxNxZ. In matlab numel is not the same as length which will print out max(N,M,Z), and I believe the same holds for Java.

Comment: This may be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698823/how-to-ask-2-dimensional-java-array-for-its-number-of-rows

Comment: In Java "rows" of multidimensional arrays can have different size, like `int[][] myArray = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5, 6 } };`. How `numel(myArray)` should react on that kind of data?

Comment: Most often I encounter `numel` in the context as an iterator over all elements. Almost always you can replace it with some pattern in Java. Think iterator, aggregator or mapper.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is how you want `numel` to work but here you have few versions:

### version1 - for arrays with irregular size like {{1},{2,3}}

this method will iterate over all elements of array counting them.

```
public static int numel(Object array) {
    if (array == null)
        return 1;// I will count nulls as elements since new String[10] is
                    // initialized with nulls 
    int total = 1;
    if (array.getClass().isArray()) {
        total = 0;
        int length = java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(array);
        for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
            total += numel(java.lang.reflect.Array.get(array, index));
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

### version2 - for arrays with regular size like new String[2][3][4]

this method will only use size of first rows of different levels in array to get it size assuming that rows at same level have same size

```
public static int regularNumel(Object array) {
    if (array == null)
        return 1;
    int total = 1;
    if (array.getClass().isArray()) {
        int length = java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(array);
        if (length > 0) {
            Object row = java.lang.reflect.Array.get(array, 0);
            if (row == null || !row.getClass().isArray())
                return length;
            else //now we know that row is also array
                return length * regularNumel(row);
        } else
            return 0;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The numel function of matlab

n = numel(A) returns the the number of elements, n, in array A.

You Can make yours like

```
int arraycount(int a[])
    {
    int counter;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
    counter++;
    }
    return counter;
    }
```

Comment: I believe this will give 3 if the array is 3x3, or even 3x3x3

Answer (score -1):

```
class main{
    public static void main (String[] args){
    // numel returns the number of array elements, as does .length in Java.
    int[] testArr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    System.out.println(testArr.length);
    }
}
// Result: 8
```

Comment: I believe this will give 3 if the array is 3x3, or even 3x3x3

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve this problem.

How I wish the size of an image, I made a small function that solved my problem.

```
 public static int length(BufferedImage bi)
{
    int x;
    x=bi.getHeight()*bi.getWidth();
    return x;
}
```

Comment: How this is connected with your question? How people should know that you ware trying to get size of BufferedImage?

Comment: Probably i don't find the best way to explain my question.

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with your question. Next time describe WHAT are you trying to achieve and then show HOW ware you trying to do it. Without it people wont be able to help you.

Comment: Take a look at XyProblem [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)